# Flutter : How to format the elements of the Bottom Navigation Bar and add colors and borders with radius

Tags: flutter

[image: This is a design by figma]

I want to make such a design, but I could not design the shopping cart icon in this format, how can I do it?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp( MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart ,), label:'',
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), label:''),

          ],

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the code I tried to do, I couldn't format the basket icon as shown in the figma design image

Comment: Could you provide a code example of your `BottomNavigationBar` widget?

Comment: yes,I have modified the question

Comment: Try to play with shadow, can be used BoxDecoration, you can check `neumorphic design` concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create and `empty text` with widget option list (`_widgetOptions`)
2. Create a `BottomNavigationBarItem with empty label` and in the icon widget, place `container with BoxShape.circle` decoration and use a `custom icon` of container child
3. Use `selected and unselected item color` property
4. In the `_onItemTapped` set a condition for the middle selection icon

[image]

See the full codes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  
  static const TextStyle optionStyle = TextStyle(
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  );

  static const List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Text(
      'Index 0: Home',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 1: Business',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      '',
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 3: School',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
    Text(
      'Index 4: Settings',
      style: optionStyle,
    ),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    if (index != 2) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedIndex = index;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('BottomNavigationBar Sample'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              height: 65,
              width: 65,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.shopping_cart,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
          const BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.blue[800],
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help..
But until now I couldn't apply the inner shadow of the icon and I tried to understand it and I read https://www.hourglazz.dev/tutorials/neumorphic-button-designs-in-flutter

But I couldn't apply it to the format, can you help me please?

Comment: You can use the flutter_neumorphic (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic) package and just change the container with icon.

Comment: Another easy way is that just export the icon with the rounded inner shadow and then change the icon container with the custom icon asset like this: https://pastebin.com/WpmJEt3s

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code for the first `BottomNavigationBarItem` so it has red circular background:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
    icon: Container(
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.red,
        ),
        child: Icon(
            Icons.shopping_cart,
            color: Colors.white,
        ),
    ),
    label: '',
),
```

You can change the values of `height`, `width` and `color` to match your needs.

Also, I would recommend adding these parameters to your `BottomNavigationBar` to center the icons (use it only if you are going to keep all of the labels as empty strings):

```
showSelectedLabels: false,
showUnselectedLabels: false,
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.. But until now I couldn't apply the inner shadow of the icon and I tried to understand it and I read hourglazz.dev/tutorials/neumorphic-button-designs-in-flutter But I couldn't apply it to the format, can you help me please? –